# Get config variable value in hook_block_list_alter

Tags: blocks

works I have added a new field to block configuration settings by using the function  `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`. I used submit handler to save the variable `$form['#submit'][] = mymodule_submit` (as block_save function was not called). Its all done till here

Now I am trying to alter the block list based on the condition set in the config field `enable_conectivity`

```
function mymodule_block_list_alter(&$blocks) {


    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
       $enable_conectivity =??//How to get the varibale value
        if($enable_conectivity) {
            $blocks[$key]->visibility = BLOCK_CUSTOM_DISABLED;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to call function hook_block_view it is not called instead hook_block_view_alter works.

---

#### Issue:Saving is affecting all the blocks

```
function mymodule_submit($form, &$form_state) {
     variable_set('url_to_check', $form_state['values']['url_to_check']);
     variable_set('enable_check', $form_state['values']['enable_check']);
}
```

hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()

```
$form['visibility']['mycustom'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('ConnectCheck'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#group' => 'visibility',
 '#weight' => 20,
);
$form['visibility']['mycustom']['enable_check'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Show block only when user can connect to internet'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('enable_check', FALSE),
);
$form['visibility']['mycustom']['url_to_check'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Url to check'),
   '#maxlength' => 90,
   '#default_value' => variable_get('url_to_check', 'www.google.com'),
   '#states' => array(
     'visible' => array(
        'input[name="enable_check"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I am trying to disable the block which requires to connect internet.
It should disable to only those user who do not have internet access.

Comment: unset the block in hook_block_list_alter rather than setting visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've set the variable using the [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) function, you can get the value using the [`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) function.

From the docs:

> Returns a persistent variable.
>
> Case-sensitivity of the variable_* functions depends on the database collation used. To avoid problems, always use lower case for persistent variable names.

In your case the `foreach` loop would become :

```
foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
  $enable_conectivity = variable_get('enable_conectivity', TRUE); // Default value of `TRUE` is returned if the variable is not set.
  if($enable_conectivity) {
    $blocks[$key]->visibility = BLOCK_CUSTOM_DISABLED;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajit. I have one more problem saving the variables affect all the blocks not just one. Why?

Comment: $blocks[$key]->visibility = BLOCK_CUSTOM_DISABLED is not disabling the block